# Drupal 6 - error message for custom login form remains empty

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using garland's theme for my Drupal 6 administrator. I added a template called: *page-user-login.tpl.php* which I can access from *mywebiste.com/user/login*. Inside the template I simply added:

```
<html ...>
<head>
  <?php print $head ?>
  <?php print $styles ?>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    print drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
    print $messages;
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The login form gets displayed and is working correctly for existing users.

However, if a user doesn't exists, no messages are displayed on the page.  I tried using "theme_status_messages" and "drupal_get_messages" but they always are empty. What should I do in order to get the return error message?

PS: I'm creating a custom login page because it needs a complete different design than all the other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user login form is already loaded up in the $content variable.

```
<?php print $content; // instead of print drupal_get_form(... ?>
```

I had a similar page override, so I just dropped in  your method and confirmed errors do not display (user field does highlight red though).  Errors do display when I print $content though.

My guess is it has to do with 2 of the same form being retrieved in the same page request.

Answer (score 1):

Page templates should have a preprocessed variable for messages:

```
<?php print $messages; ?>
```

(from [here](http://drupal.org/node/11812))

drupal_get_messages() is empty in the page template because it was already called on preprocess, to build the $messages variable.  When that function is called the messages session variable is cleared.

Are you putting that into your page template anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I also tried with print $messages; but nothing gets printed at all. I updated my question to show the full content of my template. Thanks!

Comment: hmmmmm.... thats odd. are you still calling drupal_get_messages() anywhere? or theme_status_messages()?  those do clear the message session...

Comment: or... (this one is a puzzler) another issue with the anonymous user sessions could be related to the "user 0" -- [read more on that here](http://devbee.com/all_important_user_zero)